# Jagged array value assignment changes entire array

Tags: python, arrays, jagged-arrays

So I am trying to make a jagged array just like in other languages like C#, Java.

I tried using this code

```
array = [[0] * 5] * 5
print(list(array))
```

Which gave this output

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Which is great!

---

But the issue is when I try to modify a value in this array, all the arrays get modified.
Here is the code:

```
array = [[0] * 5] * 5
array[2][3] = 5
print(list(array))
```

And this is the output

```
[[0, 0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0]]
```

What I was hoping for is something similar to this

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Any idea why this value assignment is happening to all the arrays?